# Internet Explorer loses connection if executing a php file with no html inside it? is this possible?

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have here a PHP page that gets a list of files from a directory, then does a header redirect based on what it has found. There is no HTML in this file.

Get this:

In Internet Explorer the connection is lost on that page. The browser stops without redirect, and stays on this php page saying connection lost.

This doesn't happen in Chrome. The page takes about 2 seconds at most to redirect.

And because I included some html underneath the php script in this php file, suddenly IE doesn't loose connection. The php page does what it's meant to, and redirects to an appropriate page, same as Chrome.

Does this make any sense to anyone? Would IE loose a connection to a page if it couldn't find any HTML on it?
Could anyone explain what is going on?

It's Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 m